# Image-hover-effect in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, image

I am attaching the image below.
Can someone help me with the code and tell me why hovering effect doesn't occur over Image here.
Below is the `code snippet :`
[Css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0kVm.png)

[Js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPHk.png)

Final output is just the image with no hover effect :[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vteCm.png)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that you are separating the "deg" from the number you want to rotate. It would be:

```
.container:hover img{
      transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.5);
 }
```

You can test it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-moore-jem2j?file=/src/Card.css